# Singleton alphabet smallest grammar problem. Would this be easier work with?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, formal-languages, semigroups, discrete-optimization

I want to prove that for strings $s$ over a singleton alphabet $\Sigma = \{a\}$, if $s = a^{x\cdot y}, \ x,y \neq 1$, then there exists a smallest grammar derived from the grammar:
$$
S \to A^x \\
A \to a^y
$$

By derived, I mean you can then compute a smallest grammar solely by creating new rules and collapsing variables.  My intuition tells me that this is the case.  **This is interesting because now the problem has been effectively divided-and-conquered, as $\{a\} \cap \{A\} = \varnothing$ are disjoint alphabets** and so you proceed by computing the smallest grammar of $A^x$ alone and of $a^y$ alone, and simply union the resultant rule sets.

Of course, we would need to handle the case where $x$ or $y$ is prime, and for that, we would make another lemma, saying that a smallest grammar is any smallest grammar of $a^{x-1}$ with $a$ appended to the start rule.  My intuition also tells me that is the case.

For example $s = a^8$, then $S \to A^4; A \to a^2$ is clearly a smallest grammar.

---

My idea is to look at all possible substiututions of repeated substrings.  For the case $s = a^8$, we have:

$$
A = a^2, \ B = aA, \ C = aB = A^2
$$

Those are the only possibilities.  Now define $\varphi(C) = aB; \ \varphi(x) = x$ elsewhere; then we can get from the reduced grammar $S \to C^2$ to $S \to (aB)^2$ simply by applying $\varphi$ to the rule string $C^2$.

Can we somehow define a finite semigroup of $\varphi$'s and magically say that we've tried all possible combinations?

---

What's nice about the singleton alphabet is that all variables commute with each other and $a$!  If the above can be proved, then we've proven that at least over a singleton alphabet, the smallest grammar problem is easy.  This comes from the fact that factoring the exponent $n = x\cdot y$ can be done naively in time $\sqrt n $ and $n = |s|$ is the length of the input so, the algorithmn, because it divides and conquers will turn out to be polynomial in $|s|$.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a smallest grammar? Least number of rules? Least number of different non-terminals? Least number of symbols in the rules? ...  You do not really state your target language either. Just the singleton languages?

Comment: @PeterLeupold its the total number of symbols on the right-hand side.  These are single string grammars, so the language the generate is the input string.  I've given up on the problem.  Too difficult!  It's one of those easy to state problems that will require super advanced techniques to solve in either direction (easy problem or hard problem).

Comment: Thanks @EnjoysMath, now I understand. Maybe the smallest grammar would be one building a binary tree over the word like: S->AA, A->BB, B->CC etc. with some special treatment for the last level, when the strings's length is not a full power of 2. You only gain weight 2 with every power of two.

Comment: The "special treatment" might be hard to do. So I modify my proposal: Take the binary representation of the string's length. For every 1 generate a non-terminal. For each of these non-terminals generate the binary tree of corresponding height. You only need the rules for the largest one, the others can recycle these by starting from the non-terminal corresponding to their height. The size of the grammar should be logarithmic in the length of the string.